# Linking FFTW into an Android NDK application

Tags: android, static-libraries, android-ndk, fftw

I am currently writing a genre classification application as my final year project in Computer Engineering.  I initially wrote the feature extraction code (implementing FFTW) in C and now I need to implement it on Android via the NDK.

This is my first NDK project so I'm still getting the hang of things but I have compiled the FFTW3 library for Android according to [this guide](http://blog.jimjh.com/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2.html). I didn't do the very last step because I didn't think it was right for what I need.

My question is how do I, after the compile step, use the library in the main NDK application that calls on it? Do I everything normally in Application.mk just with LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES set to the libfftw3.a that I just compiled? And then I don't need to have any -lfftw3 linker flags like I normally would right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use prebuit FFTW library (no matter how did you build it).

Or you can build FFTW in `Android.mk` makefile with the whole project.

`Android.mk` content will be:

```
# Prebuilt FFTW library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := fftw
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# or

# Build FFTW library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := fftw
# TODO put your static libs build flags
include path_to_fftw_sources/$(LOCAL_MODULE).mk
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := YourProject
# TODO put your shared lib build flags
include path_to_your_project/$(LOCAL_MODULE).mk
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += fftw
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have written `path_to_fftw_sources/$(LOCAL_MODULE).mk` for building fftw static library and `path_to_your_project/$(LOCAL_MODULE).mk` for building your shared library. It is often better to put `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` and `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` to the separate `.mk` file.

You can read more about `Android.mk` file in `docs/ANDROID-MK.html` document in your NDK distribution.