# Android NDK: no archive symbol table

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk

I'm trying to port the `FFTW` library and some `.cpp` files to Android, using the 2.1.5 version of `FFTW`. I compiled it using the configure & make commands and I try to use it as a pre-built library. In my `NDK` project everything compiles with no errors, but when linking I get the following error:

```
Compile++ thumb  : water <= vertex.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : water <= face.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : water <= Solver.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : water <= Water.cpp
SharedLibrary  : libwater.so
/Users/Xavi/Documents/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: /Users/Xavi/Documents/workspace/mmm/obj/local/armeabi/libfftw.a: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
```

My Android.mk code is the following

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := fftw
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := fftw/lib/libfftw.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := water
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/water/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
water/src/vertex.cpp \
water/src/face.cpp \
water/src/Solver.cpp \
water/src/Water.cpp 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := fftw
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it better to compile the `FFTW` library in a different way?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234629/linking-fftw-into-an-android-ndk-application

Comment: What compiler did you use to build FFTW?  You need to either generate a stand alone android toolchain, adapt the FFTW to the ndk build system (Android.mk etc), or use one of the now obsolete wrapper hacks - you cannot simply invoke the android toolchain binaries form the ndk distribution the way you would those from some ordinary cross compiler.

Comment: The library was build with the Apple `cc` compiler, version 3.1. I will try to compile the library via ndk, but then I think I don't understand how to use pre-built libraries

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
ROOT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH = $(ROOT_PATH)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra

LOCAL_MODULE    := water

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := fftw3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
water/src/vertex.cpp \
water/src/face.cpp \
water/src/Solver.cpp \
water/src/Water.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And I used android ndk toolchain to build fftw 
this is my build.sh. Put this in your android project folder and run it and put fftw folder in the parent folder

```
#!/bin/sh
# fftw3/build.sh
# Compiles fftw3 for Android
# Make sure you have NDK_ROOT defined in .bashrc or .bash_profile

INSTALL_DIR="`pwd`/app/jni/fftw3"
SRC_DIR="`pwd`/../fftw-3.3.4"

cd $SRC_DIR

export
  PATH="<your path>/android-ndk-r11c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-  4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin:$PATH"
export SYS_ROOT="<your path>/android-ndk-r11c/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/"
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export RANLIB="arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"
export STRIP="arm-linux-androideabi-strip"

mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --build=x86_64-apple-darwin --   
prefix=$INSTALL_DIR LIBS="-lc -lgcc"

make 
make install 

exit 0
```

And you will find fftw folder in app/jni and it will include bin, include,lib,share folders and in lib folder you will find libfftw3.a