# Android NDK: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am updating my projects to use Android ndk 16b and it was previously using 12b (was working fine). After I updated, I am running into the following error while building the final .so:

```
/Users/ssk/code/client/git/thirdparty/android-ndk-r16b/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: jni/../../../shared-library/SharedCommon/build/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/libSharedCommon.a: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
```

This is leading to a bunch of linker errors. I tried the following answers:

[Android NDK: no archive symbol table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751560/android-ndk-no-archive-symbol-table#37853847)

[How to run ranlib on an archive built through Android.mk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340060/how-to-run-ranlib-on-an-archive-built-through-android-mk)

[no archive symbol table (run ranlib) while building libcryptopp.a through ndk-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043538/no-archive-symbol-table-run-ranlib-while-building-libcryptopp-a-through-ndk-bu)

with no luck.

Answer (score 6):

You need to build static libraries with a GNU AR (like the one we include in the NDK, same directory as GCC). Darwin's AR is a BSD AR that does not automatically perform ranlib tasks.

Answer (score 0):

When cross compiling a library for android, I encounter similar issue.

The problem arouse because I didn't specify ranlib tool for cross compiling, and it fallback to use a default one in the build system which is x86.

The issue solved by specifying the ranlib to `arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib` in configuration stage before compiling.

Answer (score 0):

For one of my library adding

```sh
NDK=$HOME/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/
cmake -DCMAKE_RANLIB=$NDK/x86_64-linux-android-ranlib ...
```

fixed the issue. For another one library it didn't work and needed adding also

```sh
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB=$NDK/x86_64-linux-android-ranlib -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB=$NDK/x86_64-linux-android-ranlib ...
```

Also you may need add reference to `ar` ndk tool

```sh
-DCMAKE_AR=$NDK/x86_64-linux-android-ar
```

Adding `C` or `CXX` depends on what you using gcc/clang or gcc++/clang++. To set right compiler use flags like `DCMAKE_C_COMPILER` or `DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` for `cmake`.