# NDK link C++ library .a error, no archive symbol table (run ranlib)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

## description

We have a C/C++ project [wallet-core](https://github.com/IFWallet/wallet-core/tree/free_cash) that is using third party library [libsecp256k1](https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/secp256k1), and we install libsecp256k1 into `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`, all works well in wallet-core Unit Test, till we add it to android, which call wallet-core.

call links:
`android project -> wallet-core -> trezor_crypto -> libsecp256k1`

When we run `tools/android-test`, got error in link period:

```
xxxx -L/usr/local/lib trezor-crypto/libTrezorCrypto.a  libprotobuf.a  -llog  /usr/local/lib/libsecp256k1.a  -latomic -lm && :
  /Users/bibodeng/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /usr/local/lib/libsecp256k1.a: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
  ../../../../../../trezor-crypto/src/ecdsa.c:1211: error: undefined reference to 'secp256k1_context_create'
  ../../../../../../trezor-crypto/src/ecdsa.c:1213: error: undefined reference to 'secp256k1_schnorr_sign'
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

  Configuring for JNI
```

two function is undefined and there is no symbols, tell me ranlib. ranlib result:

```
$ranlib libsecp256k1.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: libsecp256k1.a(/0) size too large (archive member extends past the end of the file)
```

I run `nm -g libsecp256k1.a` also said it's truncated or malformed archive.

Please help me to solve this problem, we have stuck several days. Thanks a lot.

## guess reason

I read many answer and guess it's reason:

1. linker will run ranlib before link, but it fail cause there is no
   symbol ranlib failed because `libsecp256k1.a`
2. archive file is too big or maybe not in good format
3. `libsecp256k1.a` file is not
   generated well or ranlib has problems.

## codes & config

libsecp256k1: https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/secp256k1

```
./autogen.sh
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --enable-module-schnorr
make
make check
sudo make install
```

wallet-core: https://github.com/IFWallet/wallet-core/tree/free_cash

```
git clone git@github.com:IFWallet/wallet-core.git
git checkout free_cash
cd wallet-core
./bootstrap.sh
./tools/android-test
```

download the codes from github and checkout `free_cash` branch, run upper cmd will get the same error.

## relate answers

I already try this answer, but not work.
[ndk-no-archive-symbol-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397410/android-ndk-no-archive-symbol-table-run-ranlib)

Comment: It looks like you are compiling those dependencies with your host (macOS) compiler, and trying to link them into x86_64 Android binary? That will not work. You need to use the Android cross-compiler for everything.

Comment: Okay, so can you give some advice about cross-compiler? my project has a library trezor_crypto, it works for ndk, but when using third party library, how to config cross-compiler for third party library?

Comment: See the [Android developer page on cross-compiling](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#autoconf)